# Open data URI from c# in default browser

Tags: c#, browser, uri

I have a string that is a data URI. For example

```
string dataURI = data:text/html,<html><p>This is a test</p></html>
```

Then I call the web browser by using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dataURI)
```

But the web browser doesn't open, I just get an error. When I paste my data URI into the browser adress bar, it opens the page just fine.

Can anyone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you, Tony

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: it's in German :(
I translates something like: Run failed. The target caused an exception.

Answer (score 2):

As per this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816),

> > ShellExecute parses the string that is passed to it so that ShellExecute can extract either a protocol specifier or an extension. Next, ShellExecute looks in the registry and then uses either the protocol specifier or the extension to determine which application to start. If you pass http://www.microsoft.com to ShellExecute, ShellExecute recognizes the http:// sub-string as a protocol.

In your case there is no `http` substring. So you have to explicitly pass the default browser executable as file name and data URI as parameter. I used the `GetBrowserPath` code from this [article](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/16/649.aspx).

```
string dataURI = "data:text/html,<html><p>This is a test</p></html>";
string browser = GetBrowserPath();
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(browser))
    browser = "iexplore.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = browser;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = dataURI;
p.Start();

private string GetBrowserPath()
{
    string browser = string.Empty;
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = null;
    try
    {
        // try location of default browser path in XP
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"HTTP\shell\open\command", false);
        // try location of default browser path in Vista
        if (key == null)
        {
            key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http", false); ;
        }
        if (key != null)
        {
            //trim off quotes
            browser = key.GetValue(null).ToString().ToLower().Replace("\"", "");
            if (!browser.EndsWith("exe"))
            {
                //get rid of everything after the ".exe"
                browser = browser.Substring(0, browser.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 4);
            }                    
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (key != null) key.Close();
    }
    return browser;
}
```

Comment: I tried your method, but somehow it didn't work. It called the browser correctly but only passed part of the URI.

Anyway, now I created a temp file and have the browser display that instead of the data URI, works flawlessly. But I appreciate your help, it made me understand the problem.